# Multivariable Lipschitz continuous functions that can be written as a linear combination of a function

Tags: lipschitz-functions

Let $f_i$ ($i=1, \ldots, n$) be globally Lipschitz continuous functions which can be expressed as

$\left[\begin{array}{c} f_1(x_1, \ldots, x_n) \\ \vdots \\ f_n(x_1, \ldots, x_n)\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{ccc} a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn}\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{c} g(x_1) \\ \vdots \\ g(x_n)\end{array}\right].$

where $a_{ii} \neq 0$ for all $i$.

Can we say that the scalar function $g$ is globally Lipschitz continuous?

Comment: If all the $a_{ij}$ are $0$, then $g$ could be anything. You'll need some conditions one the $a_i$, but probably not something too constraining.

Comment: You are right, $a_{ii} \neq 0$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

First, the case where there the line $j=1$ has a sum $\sum_i a_{1i}\neq 0$.
Then we study on the diagonal $x := x_1 = x_2 = \dots = x_n$, and the answer is fast.
$$g(x) = \frac {f_1(x,x,\dots,x)} {\sum_i a_{1i}}$$

Else, we study on the pseudo-diagonal $x := x_2 = \dots = x_n$ with $x_1 := 0$, which gives :
$$g(x) = \frac {f_1(0,x,\dots,x) - a_{11}g(0)} {\sum_{i\ge 2} a_{1i}}$$
Where the denominator is not $0$ because it is equal to $-a_{11}$ because the line 1 has null sum.

In both case, we have easy proofs that $g$ has almost any regularity that the $f_i$ have.